# Is second derivative of a convex function convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

If $f$ is twice differentiable and convex, is it true that $f''$ is a convex function ?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What examples of convex functions do you know of?

Comment: What would happen if you took two successive antiderivatives of a positive, non-convex function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought I'd take a personal challenge to find a counterexample on the entire real line. Here's a method for constructing such a function: let $g_1(x)$ be any nonconvex but positive real function such that the integrals $g_2(x)=\int_{0}^x g_1(z) dz$, and $g_3(x)=\int_{0}^x g_2(z) dz$ both exist for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $g_3$ is convex, but its second derivative $g_1$ is not.

If you'd like a specific example, consider 
$$f(x) = x \mathop{\textrm{erf}}(x) + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2}$$
I chose this deliberately, because
$$f'(x) = \mathop{\textrm{erf}}(x), \quad
f''(x) = \tfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2}.$$

The function:

[image: The function:]

The second derivative:

[image: The second derivative:]

Comment: Well, personal challenges are often how interesting things are found.  Nice example!

Answer (score 9):

$f(x) = -\sin x$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ is a counterexample: $f''(x) = \sin x > 0 $for all $x \in (0,\pi/2)$ while $f''''(x) = - \sin x < 0$ for all $x \in (0,\pi/2)$

this should probably be the easiest non trivial example :)

Comment: That's a particularly long username.

Comment: But not hard to remember...

Comment: no it isn't, indeed :D

Answer (score 4):

A polynomial that works is $x^6-2x^5+5x^2$. The second derivative is $10(3x^4-4x^3+10)$, and is always $\ge 0$. But the fourth derivative is $120(3x^2-2x)$, which is negative in the interval $\left(0,\frac{2}{3}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Could you name a function that has continuous first and second derivative functions, has $ \ f'' > 0 \ $ everywhere, but for which $ \ f'' \ $ itself has zero curvature?  How about $ \ f(x) = x^2 \ $ ?

EDIT: It seems pretty hard to find (at least) an *elementary* function that is convex *everywhere*, for which the second derivative function is concave everywhere.  If you can be satisfied with just an interval, $ \ f(x) = -\arctan x \ $ for $ \ x > 0 \ $ is convex everywhere on the interval, but $ \ f''(x) \ $ is not.

[image]

Comment: The function $f(x)=2$ is (trivially) convex *and* concave. Are you thinking of *strictly* convex?

Comment: All right, sorry, I didn't know a constant function was considered a "threshold case"; I guess I thought convexity wouldn't be meaningful for it.

Comment: It is impossible for a strictly concave function to be positive on the entire real line. So you won't be able to find a convex function with a strictly concave second derivative unless you restrict the domain. Of course, concavity is not the goal here, just nonconvexity.

Comment: Yes, I should have considered that:  after finding the arctangent example, it occurred to me that the best one could hope for would be to push the points of inflection of $ \ f'' \ $ further out from the y-axis , but one cannot do so indefinitely...

Answer (score 1):

integrate a positive function twice, then we get a convex function. So just find a non convex positive function is enough. Say, let $f''(x)=\sin(x)+1$, then $f(x)=x^2-\sin(x)$ is convex, but $f''$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Take any hyperbola that opens up. For example, consider the function

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$$

which looks like the absolute value function, but with the sharp point smoothed out.

[image: smoothed absolute value function]

There is some finite curvature near the "pointy end" of the function at $x=0$, but the curvature goes to zero as one moves away in either direction towards $\pm \infty$. So, the second derivative looks like a "bump", which is not convex.